# Spotify api returning invalid refresh token even though the refresh token is new

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, refresh-token, oauth-refresh-token

I'm trying  to get new access token from spotify by sending the refresh token to spotify token endpoints but it's returning this {error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Invalid refresh token'}

this is my code:

```
const basic = Buffer.from(
         `${import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID}:${import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_SECRET}`
      ).toString("base64");
      const params = new URLSearchParams();
      params.append("grant_type", "refresh_token");
      params.append("refresh_token", import.meta.env.VITE_REFRESH_TOKEN);

      const response = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
         method: "POST",
         headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${basic}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
         },
         body: params.toString()
      });

      const result = await response.json();
      return result;
```

It's suppose to return a new access token but it's returning error for some reasons i don't understand.

Note: I got the access token and refresh token from this website https://alecchen.dev/spotify-refresh-token/ after inputting my client id and client secret. If i use the access token directly to make a request to spotify api it works but i need to refresh it to get a new one but it's returning error

Answer (score 0):

You needs to call this format in body of POST.

```
grant_type = refresh_token
refresh_token = <received refresh_token>
access_token= <received access_token>
```

[image]

The website https://alecchen.dev/spotify-refresh-token/  has a potential `leak` your credential.

I will shows getting refresh token in local and update refresh token.

#### Demo Code.

Save as `get-token.js` file.

```
const express = require("express")
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

CLIENT_ID = "<your client id>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<your client secret>"
REDIRECT_URI = '<your redirect URI>' // my case is 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
SCOPE = [
    "user-read-email",
    "playlist-read-collaborative"
]

app.get("/login", (request, response) => {
    const redirect_url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${SCOPE}&state=123456&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`
    response.redirect(redirect_url);
})

app.get("/callback", async (request, response) => {
    const code = request.query["code"]
    await axios.post(
        url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        data = new URLSearchParams({
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
            'code': code
        }),
        config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            params: {
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
            },
            auth: {
                username: CLIENT_ID,
                password: CLIENT_SECRET
            }
        })
        .then(resp1 => {
            axios.post(
                url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                data = new URLSearchParams({
                    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
                    'refresh_token': resp1.data.refresh_token,
                    'access_token': resp1.data.access_token
                }),
                config = {
                    auth: {
                        username: CLIENT_ID,
                        password: CLIENT_SECRET
                    }
                }
            ).then(resp2 => {
                return response.send(JSON.stringify([resp1.data, resp2.data]));
            })
        });

})
// your port of REDIRECT_URI
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on :3000")
```

#### Install dependencies

```
npm install express axios cors
```

#### Run a local server and access it

```
node get-token.js
```

Open your browser and enter this address

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

It will get `code` and `both tokens` then exchange the `exchanged token`.

It Will display both tokens and exchanged token in Browser.

#### Result

First red box is get `access-token` and `refresh-token`

Second red box is to grant the `refresh-token`

[image]