# Can Someone help find mistake in my javastript spotify api AccessToken fetching

Tags: javascript, access-token, spotify, spotify-app

I'm building a desktop app, collecting data from Spotify for my university but sadly I encounter a problem with fetching AccessToken.

Everytime I try to create an Authorization request AccessToken the result isn't working with the Spotify api, I noticed that my generated TOKEN is way to short compared to TOKEN on spotify.com.

I tried this code on other Servers and domains but I got the same issue. I also tried starting from 0 but again I have the same problem.

This is my JavaScript.

```js
var client_id = "";
var client_secret = "";

var access_token = null;
var refresh_token = null;


const AUTHORIZE = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
const TOKEN = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";


function handleRedirect() {
  let code = getCode();
  fetchAccessToken(code);
  window.history.pushState("", "", redirect_uri);
}

function getCode() {
  let code = null;
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  if (queryString.length > 0) {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    code = urlParams.get('code')
  }
  return code;
}

function requestAuthorization() {
  client_id = "client_id ";
  client_secret = "client_secret ";
  localStorage.setItem("client_id", client_id);
  localStorage.setItem("client_secret", client_secret);

  let url = AUTHORIZE;
  url += "?client_id=" + client_id;
  url += "&response_type=code";
  url += "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(redirect_uri);
  url += "&show_dialog=true";
  url += "&scope=user-read-private user-read-email user-top-read user-modify-playback-state user-read-playback-position user-library-read streaming user-read-playback-state user-read-recently-played playlist-read-private";
  window.location.href = url;
}

function fetchAccessToken(code) {
  let body = "grant_type=authorization_code";
  body += "&code=" + code;
  body += "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(redirect_uri);
  body += "&client_id=" + client_id;
  body += "&client_secret=" + client_secret;
  callAuthorizationApi(body);
}

function refreshAccessToken() {
  refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
  let body = "grant_type=refresh_token";
  body += "&refresh_token=" + refresh_token;
  body += "&client_id=" + client_id;
  callAuthorizationApi(body);
}

function callAuthorizationApi(body) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", TOKEN, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(client_id + ":" + client_secret));
  xhr.send(body);
  xhr.onload = handleAuthorizationResponse;
}

function handleAuthorizationResponse() {
  if (this.status === 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(data);

    if (data.access_token !== undefined) {
      access_token = data.access_token;
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);

      if (data.refresh_token !== undefined) {
        refresh_token = data.refresh_token;
        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", refresh_token);
      }
    }

    onPageLoad();
  } else {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    alert(this.responseText);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the JAVA? On your server?

Comment: Also you likely do not want to publish your API credentials on the client

Comment: Yes, sory for misunderstanding

Comment: you need to run local server for getting authorization code. This is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75309249/spotify-api-returning-invalid-refresh-token-even-though-the-refresh-token-is-new/75318666#75318666)